# Delete a field and its contents in all the records and recreate it with new mapping

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have a field `field10` which got created by accident when I updated a particular record  in my index. I want to remove this field from my index, all its contents and recreate it with the below mapping:

```
"mytype":{
  "properties":{
    "field10":{ 
      "type":"string",
      "index":"not_analyzed",
      "include_in_all":"false",
      "null_value":"null"      
    }  
  }  
}
```

When I try to create this mapping using the Put Mapping API, I get an error: `{"error":"MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [field10] has different index values, mapper [field10] has different index_analyzer, mapper [field10] has different search_analyzer]}]","status":400}`.

How do I change the mapping of this field? I don't want to reindex millions of records just for this small accident.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't remove a single field and recreate it.
You can not either just modify a mapping and have everything reindexed automagicaly. Imagine that you don't store `_source`. How can Elasticsearch know what your data look like before it was indexed?

But, you can probably modify your mapping using a multifield with `field10.field10` using the old mapping and `field10.new` with the new analyzer.

If you don't reindex, only new documents will have content in `field10.new`.
If you want to manage old documents, you have to:

- Send again all your docs (it will update everything) - aka reindex (you can use scan & scroll API to get your old documents)
- Try to update your docs with the [Update API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/update.html)

You can probably try to run a query like:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/crunchbase/person/1/_update -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.field10 = ctx._source.field10"
}'
```

But, as you can see, you have to run it document by document and I think it will take more time than reindexing all with the Bulk API.

Does it help?